# i386mingw32-g++ not created :(

Tags: g++, mingw

I have installed the MinGW cross compiler in Linux, but I'm not able to create `i386mingw32msvc-g++` because of which I'm not able to cross compile my C++ application. What has to be done to create it?

In `/usr/local/cross-tools/bin`, I've all these executables,

- i386-mingw32-addr2line
- i386-mingw32-ar
- i386-mingw32-as
- i386-mingw32-gcc
- i386-mingw32-gcc-3.4.2
- i386-mingw32-gccbug
- i386-mingw32-c++filt
- i386-mingw32-cpp
- i386-mingw32-size
- etc.

but not i386mingw32msvc-g++

How do I create it in bin?

Answer (score 0):

Just use i386-mingw32-g++ & friends as i386-mingw32msvc-g++ etc - e.g. alias. They are for all intent and purpose the same thing.